# apache Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'. > com.android.build.api

Tags: android, apache, android-gradle-plugin

When i build and run the project on my nexus 5 device, it works well. But then, when I build and run the project on my Samsung GT-I9100(api 16), it shows error of :

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
```

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lorg/apache/http/Consts;

then I add the `multiDexEnabled true` to my gradle. When i try to compile again, now I get following error message 
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lorg/apache/http/Consts;

but again, it is working fine when I compile it on my Nexus 5(api 23)

My app gradle file

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.project.example"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }

    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.0'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.1'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.5.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Comment: post your grade file

Comment: @Umarov Check it. I've edited them

Answer (score 0):

You have to add dependency in your gradle as well

```
 compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
```

only adding  `multiDexEnabled true` won't work since your minSkdVersion is lower then 21. see documentation here [Conifigure you apps for multidex](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html)

Also you have to extend `MultiDexApllication` in your application class instead of `Application`

Comment: I've done all you said,but the problem is still persists

Comment: @VincentTheonardo please update your your gradle changes here in question too. others may not read this comment here.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding following code in build level gradle(build.gradle)

```
dexOptions {
javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
preDexLibraries = false
}
```